# is this good enough for a RAM upgrade?

Tags: memory

currently i have this running as what I have. Any chances of increasing the RAM say to 16 / 32 GB RAM.

[image]

Can this be upgraded in anyway?

Answer (score 3):

> Any chances of increasing the RAM say to 16 / 32 GB RAM.

No.

Your processor ([Intel N3510](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/76751/intel-pentium-processor-n3510-2m-cache-2-00-ghz.html)) supports a maximum of 8GB.